# Plugin Registration Tool can't load my org in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

When I try to make a new connection to my org in Dynamics 365, it always load my default organization (my company's CRM), and not displaying my intended org. What is the way to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check "Display all organizations" checkbox before establishing connection. You will then have a dialog displaying all available orgs and you will be able to select the desired one.